# ListView clears when changing content view

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I would like to keep the content in the listview but it clears when changing from the fragment to the activity.

Here is the Fragment code for the List:

```
public class f2 extends ListFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
 }
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle pending = getArguments();
    String Number = pending.getString("Num");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    adapter.add(Number);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call setContentView(), the newly-generated ListView is not the same as the one from the first time you called setContentView() and there is absolutely **no link** between the two of them or their Adapters.

Regardless, the only solution is to *repopulate* the ListView, whether that's by creating a new Adapter entirely and re-adding each item, or by holding a reference to the Adapter outside of the Activity/Fragment and then resetting the new ListView to use that saved Adapter.